# How to add multiple ajax request in Angularjs single controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

How can I have multiple ajax response data in a single controller in angular.js?

Sample code (Controller):

First API: (Getting dashlet details from server)

```
var Api = $resource('/portal/api/notificationdashlet/'+id);
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
       page: 1,            // show first page
       count: 10,          // count per page
       sorting: {
         name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
       }
    }, {
    total: 0,           // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        // ajax request to api
        Api.get(params.url(), function(data) {
            $timeout(function() {
                //params.total(data.total);
                $defer.resolve(data.result);
                console.log(data.result);
            }, 10);
        });
    }
});
```

Second API: (Getting DOB details from server)

```
var Api1 = $resource('/portal/api/notificationdob/');
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
       page: 1,            // show first page
       count: 10,          // count per page
       sorting: {
         name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
       }
    }, {
    total: 0,           // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        // ajax request to api
        Api1.get(params.url(), function(data) {
            $timeout(function() {
                //params.total(data.total);
                $defer.resolve(data.result);
                console.log(data.result);
            }, 10);
        });
    }
});
```

View (HTML):

First API Table:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>Title<td>
        <td>Name<td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="val in $data ">
            <td>{{val.t}}</td>
            <td>{{val.n}}</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Second API Table:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>Date<td>
        <td>Desc<td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="details in $data ">
            <td>{{details.d}}</td>
            <td>{{details.des}}</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically just make two separate requests, populating the `$scope` object as result callbacks are triggered. The view will refresh automatically. If you don't want the view to refresh until all of the ajax requests are complete, then chain together some promises with `$q.all`.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q for more details about that. There are other ways to do it, but angular encourages the use of its built-in $q library. Here is an example (change the content of the ajaxStuff service to suit your needs; no server to work with here so I simulated server calls using `setTimeout`):

```js
'use strict';

/* App Module */

angular.module('testApp', [])
 .controller('test-controller', function($scope, $q, ajaxStuff){
   var promise1 = ajaxStuff.getData1();
   var promise2 = ajaxStuff.getData2();
   $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(results){
      $scope.foo = results[0];
      $scope.bar = results[1];
   });
 }).factory('ajaxStuff', function($q){
   return{
     getData1: function(){
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       setTimeout(function(){
            deferred.resolve('foo');
       }, 1000);
       return deferred.promise; 
     },
     getData2: function(){
       var deferred = $q.defer();
        setTimeout(function(){
            deferred.resolve('bar');
       }, 500);
       return deferred.promise;
     }
   };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="test-controller">
      {{foo}}{{bar}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks .Solved the issue in another way  (https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/commit/158c6c681bd01871383315423747fff26d075cfc)